# Parsing an Object into a String

Tags: java, parsing, object

Hi there I am looking to parse an Object I have into a String so that I can enter it's value into a textfield. Here is a little snippet.

TFname is the name of the textfield

```
Object value = list.getSelectedValues();
TFname.setText(parseObject(value)); //-- Here I pick up an error
```

Where I pick up the error, I know it's because this isn't how you parse an object but I was wondering if anyone knew how I would go about doing it properly.

If anyone could help I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String.valueOf(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
value.toString()
```

Comment: In general I would recommend doing String.valueOf(value) as that won't NPE.

Answer (score 0):

`list.getSelectedValues()` returns an Array of Objects. Try this code, if it fails, error details wouldbe helpful

```
Object[] value = list.getSelectedValues();
fName.setText(parseObject(value)); //-- Here I pick up an error
```

Note: I assume, there is this method in the same class:

```
String parseObject(Object[] values) {
  // method body
}
```